# Unable to open popup window using Javascript in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, content-management-system, dom-events

I am trying to open a popup window using javascript in wordpress

I have entered the following code in the edit page option:

```
<a href="javascript:void()" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', 'mywindow', 'location=no,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=500,height=650');">Click here</a>
```

The above code seems to be working fine on localhost, but it is not working on my actual Wordpress site.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work:

http://jsfiddle.net/aPmMe/

But if you're still having problems:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', 'mywindow', 'location=no,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=500,height=650');return false;">Click here</a>
```